# Gallery with multiple listboxes automatically generated from a Collection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I am trying to create a Gallery that contains multiple Listboxes from a Collection. I have a collection called **Ideas**, and it encompasses ideas from different participants. I am able to create a **Listbox** out of each participant with their ideas. However, I am trying to create a gallery that creates multiple **Listboxes** from that collection. It means if more participants are added to the collection, more **Listboxes** will automatically be created. The image shows an idea of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Gallery containing multiple ListBox]

I tried inserting a **NewGallery**, then inside the galley a **ListBox**. On **Items** inside the gallery I wrote the name of the Collections, and I got multiple **ListBoxes**, but all of them have the same information, I got something like this (only the information from one participant is displayed in 5 **ListBoxes**):

[image: Multiple ListBox with the information of one participant only]

I could individually add the listboxes on my Screen without using a gallery, however, this would not work, because I have to add manually the information every time the collection is modified.

Any idea how to add multiple ListBoxes automatically from a Collection into a Gallery in PowerApps?

Comment: What do you want to do with the list boxes? Will they all have the same items (i.e., all participants 1..n will see the same options for ideas)? Do you need to pre-select some of the items in the ideas (e.g., if a participant has chosen some of them before)?